# Excel inbuilt function

Tags: excel

I am in the process of converting a excel work book into a web based application.

The workbook performs many calculations based in input by the user. I am currently reverse engineering the formulae for these calculations.

The workbook contains many calls to the PV() function, however rather than pass implicit values, it passes either calculations or cells which are the result of other calculations to the function.

Is there any way in excel that I can see what the underlying values being passed to an inbuild function actually are?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [link](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/debug-formula-errors.htm) for how to debug formula errors

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Mick

If I understand you correctly then if you click the cell with the formula in and then click the function icon in the formula bar (*f* x) then you will see what implicit values are being used.

Alternatively, if you select `Tools > Formula Auditing > Evaluate Formula` and then click the `Evaluate` button you can cycle through each input and it will resolve the underlying value.

Happy trails.